# KendoUi Angular2 Radio And CheckBox style not working with RTL direction

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I tried to use the style k-radio and k-checkbox in angular2 application,

RTL language.

But when I try to move the Radio before Label the radio dosnt work-

cant be pressed.

It works like this:

```
<input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" [(ngModel)]="optionSearch" id="search" value="searchByTender">
<label class="k-radio-label" for="search"> </label>
```

And not work like this:

```
<label class="k-radio-label" for="search"> </label>
<input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" [(ngModel)]="optionSearch" id="search" value="searchByTender">
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It solved by using dir=rtl...

Answer (score 0):

It solved by using "dir=rtl" to all application